# Can I force my WI-FI card to be restricted to 802.11g, on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, 802.11g

I have had persistent problems with the Wi-Fi card in my iMac (early 2013). I have contacted Apple many times about it, and haven't found an adequate solution, even after discussing with an engineer.

The problems only exist in 802.11n mode; I have found that the card works well in 802.11g.

Is there a way for me to force my Wi-Fi card in my iMac to connect at 802.11g MAX, but keep the router in 802.11g/n mixed mode, in case other faster devices wish to connect?

I feel like this used to be an option in earlier Mac OS X, but in macOS Sierra, I can't find the option to limit the Wi-Fi card.